# Internal Server Error by express app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am developing a mean app. I use express-generator for scaffolding express and angular-generator to for client side. The express is running on port 3000 and angular app is running on 9000. I did an http request from angular on an API in express and got 500 error code.

The api endpoint in express looks like:

```
router.get('/fabric', function(req,res,next){
  res.send(data);
});
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('poshaqDemoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/fabric')
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.awesomeThings= response.data;
    });
  });
```

Both are running independently, I don't understand why this error is coming up

The console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGYqU.png)

Comment: The body of the error tells you the problem;  It says `Reference Error: data is not defined`.  Can you show the rest of your node code so we can help diagnose this?

Comment: Also, it's generally better to paste the **text** of the error you are receiving, rather than a **screenshot** of the error.

Comment: Thank you so much mate. I was exhausted and frustrated enough to not notice the data not defined error. @Claies

Comment: Please close or at least answer your own question.